# MySQL multiple selects?

Tags: mysql, select

I got two tables.

First with articles:
    `ID | title`
and values: 
`1 | title1 | content 1`
`2 | title2 | content 2`
`3 | title 3 | content 3`

and second with its attributes:
`artID | attrib | value`
and values:
`1 | date | 2014-06-15`
`1 | visible | true`
`1 | featured | false`
`2 | date | 2010-03-02`
`2 | visible | fals`
`2 | featured | true`
`3 | date | 2012-04-02`
`3 | visible | true`
`3 | featured | true`

(I try to show them line by line but editor here goes crazy).

artID is ID from first table.

I try to get result like this:

```
ID | title | date value | featured value | only WHERE visible = "true"
```

My try:

```
SELECT articles.ID, articles.title, attributes.artID, attributes.attrib, attributes.value
FROM articles
INNER JOIN attributes
ON articles.ID = attributes.artID
WHERE attributes.attrib=visible AND attributes.value=true
```

So now i have:

```
ID | title | (attributes.artID) | (attributes.fieldID) | (attributes.value) | only WHERE visible = "true"
```

(I don't need fields in brackets in final array)

Question is:

How to get "date" and "featured" values in same query (or other way?)

Comment: do you want just the field featured and the field date also? then you just use `attributes.featured` in your SELECT statement.

Comment: show your expected output

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid:

Expected output should be:  
ID | title | date | featured ---
1 | title1 | 2014-06-15 | false  
(2 is not visible, so excluded)  
3 | title2 | 2012-04-02 | true
One again I'm trying to show this in lines but Markdown doesn't work for me here.

Comment: @user2869150 try my answer , i have edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do so by joining attributes table 3 time for your 3 attirbutes

```
SELECT a.ID, 
a.title, 
at1.artID, 
at.value visible,
at1.value date,
at2.value featured
FROM articles a
INNER JOIN attributes at ON a.ID = at.artID
INNER JOIN attributes at1 ON a.ID = at1.artID
INNER JOIN attributes at2 ON a.ID = at2.artID
WHERE 
    at.attrib='visible'
AND at1.attrib='date'
AND at2.attrib='featured'
AND at.value ='true'
```

### [See Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/701462/4)

Answer (score 0):

I've left out att1.artID, it's duplicate.

```
SELECT articles.ID, articles.title, att1.attrib, att1.value, att2.date, att2.featured
FROM articles
INNER JOIN attributes AS att1
ON articles.ID = att1.artID
LEFT JOIN attributes AS att2
ON articles.ID = att2.artID
WHERE att1.attrib=visible AND att1.value=true
```

Comment: I'm not sure about the `INNER JOIN` on the first one... Maybe it should be a LEFT JOIN too?

Answer (score 0):

```
Select * from articles where articles.ID IN (Select artID from attributes where attrib='visible' and value='true')
```

The IN clause in MySQL allows you to specify a list of IDs. Say that IDs 1,2,3 are visible. This would be the equivalent of saying

```
Select * from articles where ID='1' OR ID='2' OR ID='3'
```

But it will dynamically generate the list. The reason your join is not working is because It will not append all of the attributes in the join, instead it will select the last attribute and append that, so you would be getting something like:

```
ID | Title | Attrib | Value
```

Not

```
ID | Title | Date | Visible | Etc
```

You would need to alter the select portion to fit what you want to select, but to get the visible records using an IN keyword is a quick and easy solution.

Answer (score 0):

try that:

```
  select id , date , featured, visible from (
  SELECT articles.ID, max(case when attrib = 'date' then value end) as 'date'
   ,max(case when attrib = 'featured' then value end) as 'featured' ,
    max(case when attrib = 'visible' then value end) as 'visible'
  FROM articles
  INNER JOIN attributes
  ON articles.ID = attributes.artID

  GROUP BY articles.ID
   )t
  WHERE  t.visible ='true'
```